# Using MEL in Mulesoft to convert a NULL value to a default value

Tags: mule

I'm using some MEL to set a variable based on the return of an SQL query -

`#[payload[0].PRTY_TYPE]`

The problem i'm having is that sometimes the `PRTY_TYPE` can come back as blank.

Rather than using exception handling, can I simply edit the MEL in the variable setting so if it's `NULL`, it gives it a default value? Like -

`IF #[payload[0].PRTY_TYPE] IS NULL THEN 'support@email.com'`

Answer (score 2):

## Mule 3

Try using a ternary expression for this:

`#[payload[0].PRTY_TYPE != null ? payload[0].PRTY_TYPE : 'support@email.com']`

You could also do this inline with DataWeave:

`#[dw("payload[0].PRTY_TYPE default 'support@email.com'")]`

---

## Mule 4

DW is the expression language in Mule 4, so you don't need to call `dw`:

`#[payload[0].PRTY_TYPE default 'support@email.com']`

Answer (score 1):

I have done this using the `or` operator. You can use `or` operator like :

```
#[payload[0].PRTY_TYPE or 'support@email.com']
```

this expression will evaluate to `support@email.com` if `payload[0].PRTY_TYPE` is `null`

According to Mule docs, you can actually go more specific on the check by checking if the property exists using the `.?` operator, like:

```
#[payload[0].?PRTY_TYPE or 'support@email.com']
```

Which I would assume to be safer.

**Reference**

For more info please check this [link](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.7/mule-expression-language-tips#chained-elements) for more on chained elements.